# Remove redundancy in help function

Tags: python

I can write the arguments but I can't avoid writing a function 'help' to print it if the command does not present the correct arguments.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
def get_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog = 'contig2genbank.py', usage= '\n\t%(prog)s [contig ID/ or list of contigs] [output prefix]' , description = "Split a .gbk (.gbff) file and retrieve the information of the contig of interest.",formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('-s', required = False, type = str, help='Name of input file (mandatory with -g)', metavar='') # used to extract single contigs
    parser.add_argument('-l', required = False, type = str, help='Name of input file  when in list (mandatory)', metavar='') # when giving a list of genomes and contigs to be extracted; see above the list example
    parser.add_argument('-g', required = False, type = str, help='Name of genome file (mandatory with -i)', metavar='') # when using a single genome, -g is the name of genome file in .gbk (.gbff) format
    return parser.parse_args()


def help():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog = 'contig2genbank.py', usage= '\n\t%(prog)s [contig ID/ or list of contigs] [output prefix]' , description = "Split a .gbk (.gbff) file and retrieve the information of the contig of interest.",formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('-s', required = False, type = str, help='Name of input file (mandatory with -g)', metavar='') # used to extract single contigs
    parser.add_argument('-l', required = False, type = str, help='Name of input file  when in list (mandatory)', metavar='') # when giving a list of genomes and contigs to be extracted; see above the list example
    parser.add_argument('-g', required = False, type = str, help='Name of genome file (mandatory with -i)', metavar='') # when using a single genome, -g is the name of genome file in .gbk (.gbff) format 
    parser.print_help()


def main():
    args = get_arguments()  # check arguments

    if args.s and args.g:
        with open(args.g, "rU") as genome: #open(args.c + '.gbk','w') as outgbk:
            for record in SeqIO.parse(genome, "genbank"):
                if args.s == record.id:
                    #with open(args.c + '.gbk','w') as outgbk:
                    SeqIO.write([record], open(record.id + ".gbk", "w"), "genbank")
        print record.id + ".gbk created."

    else:
        help()
```

What I expect is to avoid the duplication of lines in get_arguments and help functions.

Comment: If the parser failed -s and -g the first time, why do you bother to try again in the help function? Just add arg -l and print_help()

Comment: Why not just use `print_help`? And it looks like `s` and `g` arguments would be mandatory, so why do you set `required=False`?

Comment: Even if you _did_ need to do this, why construct two identical parsers? Why not just create a single parser, then use it in `parser.parse_args()` and `parser.print_help()`?

Comment: that's the point. I don't know how to do it without to repeat the parsers.

Comment: As I understood, I need to pass the 'parser' to the main function, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function `get_parser` like this:

```
def get_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog = 'contig2genbank.py', usage= '\n\t%(prog)s [contig ID/ or list of contigs] [output prefix]' , description = "Split a .gbk (.gbff) file and retrieve the information of the contig of interest.",formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('-s', required = False, type = str, help='Name of input file (mandatory with -g)', metavar='') # used to extract single contigs
    parser.add_argument('-l', required = False, type = str, help='Name of input file  when in list (mandatory)', metavar='') # when giving a list of genomes and contigs to be extracted; see above the list example
    parser.add_argument('-g', required = False, type = str, help='Name of genome file (mandatory with -i)', metavar='') # when using a single genome, -g is the name of genome file in .gbk (.gbff) format
    return parser
```

And rewrite your `main` function like this:

```
def main():
    parser = get_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()  # check arguments

    if args.s and args.g:
        with open(args.g, "rU") as genome: #open(args.c + '.gbk','w') as outgbk:
            for record in SeqIO.parse(genome, "genbank"):
                if args.s == record.id:
                    #with open(args.c + '.gbk','w') as outgbk:
                    SeqIO.write([record], open(record.id + ".gbk", "w"), "genbank")
        print record.id + ".gbk created."

    else:
        parser.print_help()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but what if you will just add a third function that is used inside the two original function, named: `get_parser`

```
def get_parser():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog = 'contig2genbank.py', usage= '\n\t%(prog)s [contig ID/ or list of contigs] [output prefix]' , description = "Split a .gbk (.gbff) file and retrieve the information of the contig of interest.",formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('-s', required = False, type = str, help='Name of input file (mandatory with -g)', metavar='') # used to extract single contigs
parser.add_argument('-l', required = False, type = str, help='Name of input file  when in list (mandatory)', metavar='') # when giving a list of genomes and contigs to be extracted; see above the list example
parser.add_argument('-g', required = False, type = str, help='Name of genome file (mandatory with -i)', metavar='') # when using a single genome, -g is the name of genome file in .gbk (.gbff) format
return parser
```

And then, the two original functions will be only two lines:
First calling `get_parser` to get it, and second to parse/print

Hope this is helpful